# SLF4J error in connection between Flume Twitter and Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter, slf4j, flume

I configured Hadoop, Flume and Twitter API correctly, but when I run this command on terminal, I get these erros, and the execution freeze.

Please, does anyone know how can I fix it? Thanks.

```
hadoopusr@wilson-VirtualBox:**~/Flume$ bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG, console -n TwitterAgent**

Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /home/hadoopusr/Flume/conf/flume-env.sh

Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access

Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access

+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/home/hadoopusr/Flume/conf:/home/hadoopusr/Flume/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/local/hadoop/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG, console -n TwitterAgent

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoopusr/Flume/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings
```

Comment: Those are warnings... Are you actually getting an error?

Comment: Also, maybe it freezes because flume nor Hadoop support Java 11